# How to append a new array of values to an existing array document in mongodb using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, mongodb-query, pymongo

An existing collection like as below:

```
"_id" : "12345",
"vals" : {
        "dynamickey1" : {}
}
```

I need to add

```
"vals" : {
            "dynamickey2" : {}
    }
```

I have tried in python 2.7 with pymongo 2.8:

```
col.update({'_id': id)},{'$push': {'vals': {"dynamickey2":{"values"}}}})
```

Error log:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: The field 'vals' must be an array but is of type object in document
```

Expected Output:

```
    "_id" : "12345",
        "vals" : {
                "dynamickey1" : {},
                "dynamickey2" : {}
                 }
```

Comment: What you call an "existing array document" is not an array at all but a hash, so you should fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

Edited following question edit:

Two options; use $set with the dot notation, or use python dict manipulation.

The first method is more MongoDB native and is one line of code; the second is a bit more work but gives more flexilbility if you use case is more nuanced.

Method 1:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.json_util import dumps

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

db.mycollection.insert_one({
    "_id": "12345",
    "vals": {
        "dynamickey1": {},
    }
})

db.mycollection.update_one({'_id': '12345'},{'$set': {'vals.dynamickey2':{}}})

print(dumps(db.mycollection.find_one({}), indent=4))
```

Method 2:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.json_util import dumps

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']


db.mycollection.insert_one({
    "_id": "12345",
    "vals": {
        "dynamickey1": {},
    }
})

record = db.mycollection.find_one({'_id': '12345'})
vals = record['vals']
vals['dynamickey2'] = {}
record = db.mycollection.update_one({'_id': record['_id']}, {'$set': {'vals': vals}})

print(dumps(db.mycollection.find_one({}), indent=4))
```

Either way gives:

```
{
    "_id": "12345",
    "vals": {
        "dynamickey1": {},
        "dynamickey2": {}
    }
}
```

Previous answer

<strike>Your expected output has an object with duplicate fields (`vals`); this isn't allowed.~</strike>

So whatever you are trying to do, it isn't going to work.